# Overlapping of Expander boundaries

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, .net-4.0

The xaml code below overlaps the boundaries of Expander.
When I run this, and click first expander option, It will expand and show rich text box. But I cannot scroll it.
But no problem with second Expander.
How to solve this problem?

```
    <Expander Header="Certificate" Margin="201,85,101,143">
        <ScrollViewer Width="283" Height="106">
            <RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="82" Width="221">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>

    <Expander Header="Challenge" Margin="201,122,86,81">
        <ScrollViewer Width="283" Height="106">
            <RichTextBox Name="richTextBox2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="82" Width="221">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>
                    11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
```

Comment: I hope you are placing Expanders inside a StackPanel. Also please avoid setting static Height and Width and Margin to arrange/place your controls on UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Expander Header="Certificate" >     
            <RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1" Width="283" Height="106" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>       
</Expander>

<Expander Header="Challenge" >         
            <RichTextBox Name="richTextBox2" Width="283" Height="106" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02 00 10 12 11 01 02
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>      
</Expander>

</StackPanel>
```